# Get Extjs grid on which context menu item is clicked

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, contextmenu, extjs6

I have a Grid and on grid context menu I am calling one function as follows-

On grids context menu I have added the following item

```
{ text: 'Preview', handler: 'PreviewGrid', scope: cnt, };
```

In controller-

```
previewGrid: function (contextMenuItem) {    
        // Here I am getting the item i.e. contextmenu item.
        // But I want here is grid on which there was right click
}
```

I tried using `item.ownerCt.up('grid')`

but it is not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see your code where and how you are instantiating the context menu, but why exactly you are dropping parameters during that process and then come ask us for help to retrieve them again? ExtJS own [`itemcontextmenu ( this , record , item , index , e , eOpts )` event](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html) is delivering the required information.

Comment: I did this but I am no way getting grid in this. Am I doing anything wrong while adding menu item?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, there's no context here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sample code: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1i9o

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 400,
            height: 500,
            title: 'itemcontextmenu',

            store: {
                fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
                data: [{
                    'name': 'Lisa',
                    "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-111-1224"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Bart',
                    "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1234"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Homer',
                    "email": "homer@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1244"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Marge',
                    "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": ""
                }]
            },
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                flex: 1
            }]
        });

        var contextMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
            width: 200,
            items: [{
                text: 'Preview',
                handler: function() {
                    var record = grid ? grid.getSelection()[0] : null;
                    if (!record) {
                        return;
                    }

                    alert(record.get('name'));
                }
            }]
        });

        grid.on("itemcontextmenu", function(grid, record, item, index, e) {
            e.stopEvent();
            contextMenu.showAt(e.getXY());
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Good example madreason

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

In grid listeners:

```
listeners: {

  itemcontextmenu: function (grid, record, item, index, e) {

     var contextMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
         height: 200,
         width: 250,
         items: [{
                text:'Preview', 
                handler: function () {
                    //code...
                }
         }]
     });
    e.stopEvent();
    contextMenu.showAt(e.getXY());
  }
}
```

Comment: You create menu every time when an item is right clicked.

Comment: Frankly, I have not found another way to do it. Works well. Example:https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1i9g

Comment: I refactored your code in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956157/get-extjs-grid-on-which-context-menu-item-is-clicked/39978577#39978577)